# C# - Combinatorics

Tags: c#, asp.net, combinatorics

I have a list of ~300 objects which all have a price and a score. I need to find the best combination (i.e. highest total score) of 15 of those objects whose total price is less than X.

The most straightforward way to do this, as I see it, is to nest 15 for loops and check every possible combination, but that would take days.

Is there any 'clean' way to do this in C#?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into using linq ?

Comment: For some reason this springs to mind https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: @DanielvanHeerden: This is actually more akin to the knapsack problem. Likely the TSP comes to mind because both it and the knapsack problem have no known polynomial time solution for the optimal case, and moreover, if *one* of them does, then the *other* one does too. It is widely believed that neither has a fast optimal algorithm.

Comment: @T0mba: As I noted in the comment above, you are on a fool's errand if you are looking for an *optimal* solution to this problem in any kind of reasonable time. There has been *over a century* of study on fast suboptimal solutions; plainly this problem is of enormous importance for tasks ranging from optimizing store shelf layout to prioritizing experiments to go to the ISS. Do a literature search and you'll find plenty of papers on this subject.

Comment: @Captain0: LINQ is not magic. It's loops behind the scenes.

Comment: I see now where I misunderstood the complexity of the problem after I read about the problems.

Comment: @Captain0 if you just mention in your post that it is a _sub-optimal_ solution in a _feasible_ amount of time, I'm pretty sure it deserves a +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to help without an example, but if I understand the problem then this might help.

Assuming your object looks like this

```
public class Item
{
        public int Score { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Then the following should sort you out.

```
var listOfObjects = new List<Item>();

var topItems = listOfObjects.Where(p => p.Price < 100).OrderByDescending(p => p.Score).Take(15);
```

**EDIT :** After all details was disclosed, the following should help

DISCLAIMER : Quick and dirty solution (sub optimal)

Create a new class

```
public class ItemWithRunningTotal
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public decimal RunningTotal { get; set; }
}
```

Then the following should get you what you need.

```
var maxTotal = 1500; //for you 8000
        var objects = new List<Item>()
                      {
                          new Item() {Score = 10, Price = 100},
                          new Item() {Score = 20, Price = 800},
                          new Item() {Score = 40, Price = 600},
                          new Item() {Score = 5, Price = 300},
                      };

        decimal runningTotal = 0;
        var newList = objects
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.Score)
            .Select(p =>
                    {
                        runningTotal = runningTotal + p.Price;
                        return new ItemWithRunningTotal()
                               {
                                   Item = p,
                                   RunningTotal = runningTotal
                               };
                    })
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.RunningTotal)
            .Where(p => p.RunningTotal <= maxTotal).Take(15);
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct but I'm afraid I was not very clear in my question:

The total price (sum) of the 15 objects may not exceed 8000, the individual price doesn't really matter.

Comment: So what should happen when the total price exceeds 8000 ? Should items of lower prices be used ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. We just want the highest possible score when using exactly 15 objects without exceeding the total cost of 8000.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking is solution for knapsack problem. There is no known way to do it fast. 
You can modify dynamic solution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem) to choose at most `maxCount` items like this:

```
public static List<Item> BestCombination(List<Item> items, int maxPrice, int maxCount)
{
    var scores = new int[items.Count + 1, maxPrice + 1, maxCount + 1];

    for (int i = 1; i <= items.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = items[i - 1];
        for (int count = 1; count <= Math.Min(maxCount, i); count++)
        { 
            for (int price = 0; price <= maxPrice; price++)
            {                    
                if (item.Price > price)
                    scores[i, price, count] = scores[i - 1, price, count];                
                else
                    scores[i, price, count] = Math.Max(
                        scores[i - 1, price, count],
                        scores[i - 1, price - item.Price, count - 1] + item.Score);
            }
        }
    }

    var choosen = new List<Item>();
    int j = maxPrice;
    int k = maxCount;
    for (int i = items.Count; i > 0; i--)
    {
        var item = items[i - 1];
        if (scores[i, j, k] != scores[i - 1, j, k])
        {
            choosen.Add(item);
            j -= item.Price;
            k--;
        }
    }            

    return choosen;
}
```

Keep in mind that choosing exaclty `maxCount` objects can give you lower total score than choosing `<= maxCount` objects. Eg for items [(100, 10), (200,20), (300,30), (500,80)], maxPrice = 500 and maxCount = 2 this method returns only (500,80). If you want it to return [(200,20), (300,30)], you can initialize array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= items.Count; i++)
{
    for (int price = 0; price <= maxPrice; price++)
    {
        for (int count = 1; count <= maxCount; count++)
        {
            scores[i, price, count] = int.MinValue;
        }
    }
}
```

to make sure that in `scores[, , count]` are sums of `count` scores (or `MinValue`). However, it still can return another number of items if there is no way to choose exactly `maxCount`.